# How to get actual path of file from sdcard with file name?

Tags: java, android

I have a file in sdcard "firmware.PTI". And i am browsing this file from my app. Below is the code i am using.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int id = v.getId();

            switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_browse_pti_file:

                Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                mediaIntent.setType("*/*"); //set mime type as per requirement
                startActivityForResult(mediaIntent, REQ_CODE_FOR_PTI);
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_FOR_PTI && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uriPTI = data.getData();
                String path = Utility.getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), uriPTI);
                Log.i(CLASSTAG, "PTI file path: "+path);
                mTvBrowsePath.setText(path);
            }
        }

public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {

        String path = null;
        if (contentUri != null)
        {
            path = contentUri.toString();
            if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://"))
            {
                // Selected file/directory path is below
                path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
            }

        }
        return path;
    }
```

If i am selecting any other file like JPEG or PNG, it is working fine and showing the correct path with file name. But, if i am selecting any .PTI file then it is getting crashed. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: `it is getting crashed`. At which moment? At which statement? With which exception? Post the logcat please. Which app did the user choose to pick the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check what the method `getRealPathFromURI` is returning because it may return `null` if `contentUri` is `null` or if `path` does not start with `file://`.

In addition to this, it is a better approach to check for the scheme in `contentUri`. Below is an updated version of your method.

```
    public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if( "content".equalsIgnoreCase( uri.getScheme() ) ) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = null;

            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Eat it
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        } else if( "file".equalsIgnoreCase( uri.getScheme() ) ) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You are using this "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA", which is for image file. Don't we have any thing for any kind of file?

Comment: @Vid Did you tried the above? I know what `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` is, but we are particularly interested in the "_data" column of the content provider. If `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` works for you then you may want to hardcode this string in your code.